# ENUMとcaseを組み合わせたテーブル作成

Tags: mysql

他の方が書いたSQLで以下のようなコードがありました。

---

```
CREATE TABLE tel(
    tel     varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    upd_date    datetime    NULL ,
    error_date  datetime    NULL ,
    status      ENUM('チェック済み','確認','エラー') AS (
        CASE
            WHEN error_date   IS NOT NULL THEN 3
            WHEN upd_date IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 2
        END CASE
    ) ST NOT NULL default 'チェック済み' ,
    PRIMARY KEY(tel)
);
```

---

upd_date、error_dateの値によってstatusにいれる値を変更したいようですが、このSQLを実行してもエラーが出て作成されませんでした。

### エラー内容

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CAS
E       ) ST NOT NULL default 'チェック済み' ,  PRIMARY KEY(tel))' at line 1
```

---

CASE付近でエラーが出ているようですが何がダメなのかわかりません。
そもそもENUMとCASEを組み合わせること自体が誤っているのでしょうか。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/82255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CASE式の最後は`END CASE`ではなく`END`です。また、生成列は式により常に値が生成されるので、デフォルト値を指定できません。

なので、次のように記述すればいいと思います。

```
CREATE TABLE tel(
    tel     varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    upd_date    datetime    NULL ,
    error_date  datetime    NULL ,
    status      ENUM('チェック済み','確認','エラー') AS (
        CASE
            WHEN error_date   IS NOT NULL THEN 3
            WHEN upd_date IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 2
        END
    ) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(tel)
);
```